# How to allow access outside localhost

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-build

How can I allow access outside the localhost at Angular2? I can navigate at `localhost:3030/panel` easily but I can not navigate when I write my IP such as `10.123.14.12:3030/panel/`.

Could you please allow me how to fix it? I am not using `npm` (node project manage - node install/node start ) to install and run the project.

If you want, I can provide my `package.json` and `index.html`.

Comment: do you use ng serve?

Comment: yes i am using ng server

Comment: did you try  ng serve --host 10.123.14.12?

Comment: I tired ng serve and it says " I have to be inside an angular--cli project in ordre to use the serve command".

Answer (score 690, accepted):

Using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` will allow you to connect to the `ng serve` using your ip instead of `localhost`.

**EDIT**

In newer versions of the cli, you have to provide your local ip address instead

**EDIT 2**

In newer versions of the cli (I think v5 and up) you can use `0.0.0.0` as the ip again to host it for anyone on your network to talk to.

Comment: it says "you have to be inside an angluar--cli project in order to use the serve command " with the red warning when i write ng sreve and also a yellow message which indicated that i am running version 6.2.2 of Node, which will not be supported in future versions of the CLI after writing ng serve

Comment: first, try updating node, second, try restarting your terminal/vscode

Comment: I updated it from package json to 6.0.46 as "@types/node": "6.0.46", but still get the same message

Comment: I found the answer myself. I was supposed to add ""server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"," to packagejson

Comment: i understand the question exactly as you asked it, adding `--host 0.0.0.0` will do what you are asking for

Comment: Please accept my answer as the correct answer so other people can find it if they have the same problem

Comment: On angular-cli 1.4.4 (webpack-dev-server 2.7.1) using `--host 0.0.0.0` causes the `'[WDS] Disconnected!'` error message. WDS websocket tries to connect to localhost, instead of the provided IP, and naturally fails to connect. Using real dev server IP instead of 0.0.0.0 as the --host argument works fine.

Comment: @AlexChe That is because it was changed on a version of the cli. At the time of answering, `0.0.0.0` was the correct answer

Comment: it works with ng serve --host 'ip adress' but when I try the name of the machine instead it doesn't work. example : 192..x.x.x:4200 works but myMachine:4200 doesn't. Any idea please ?

Comment: @John as far as i know, its for ip addresses/localhost only, not computer names

Comment: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` works fine for me.  I didn't have to use the specific IP

Comment: @Andrew yeah, i think at some point they change it again so you can use `0.0.0.0` but im not sure which version changes it. i think it was the angular 5 cli maybe but without testing, i cant be certain

Comment: you should only have to turn the firewall off if you are trying to access the server from outside your network, and in that case, you should set up ports instead

Comment: This worked for me: `ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

Comment: I've tried this but not working for me I've also added ```--disable-host-check``` still.
This is my full command:
```ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --proxy-config proxy.conf.json```

Comment: @Avishek it could be your proxy interfering perhaps? what version of angular and angular cli are you using?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon am using Angular 9 with CLI version 9.1.0

Comment: problem is when I am running my app (without build) in my system the app is working perfectly with proxy but after build this issue is occuring

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you refer to my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950609/angular-access-local-host-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/62951120?noredirect=1#comment111323822_62951120

Comment: Contrary to what this answer suggests, I had to switch my network profile (Windows 10) to **Private** in order for this to work. Not sure how it changed to Public, but this seems to make the firewall block outcoming connections.

Comment: In this context, 
Camera is not accessible in mobile browser from which  that port is running. 

any idea how can we permit camera to be accessible in  mobile browser ?

like ip:4200/takePhoto 

here takephoto is  route where it consists of camera \>

Answer (score 97):

run command

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

this will disable host check and allow to access from outside(instead of localhost) with IP address

Comment: I didn't need --disable-host-check.  `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` works fine for me.  What is the host check supposed to do?

Comment: I for once needed the `disabled-host-check` otherwise I got the message "Invalid Host header"

Comment: is there a way to define it in a config file to avoid mentioning it everytime?

Comment: @AyushKumar you can just define it in you package.json like `{ "scripts": { "start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check" } }`

Answer (score 67):

Mac users:

1. Go to System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi
2. Copy the IP address below **Status** (Usually 192.168.1.x)
3. Paste it in your ng serve like:  `ng serve --host 192.168.1.x`

Then you must be able to see your page on other devices through `192.168.1.x:4200`.

Comment: Used to work for me and not working anymore. Wondering why. I feel like I've tried everything!
My firewall is disabled. 
ng serve --host 10.x.x.x --disable-host-check
/ ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

-> Not accessible from a Windows remote machine which is on the same network with 10.x.x.x:4200

Comment: Works well in Angular 7, and MacOS 10.14.6

Comment: For what it's worth, the accepted answer is working for me on MacOS as of October 2019.

Comment: This works for me, and after searching far and wide, it is the only answer I've seen to specify this key step: in the address bar of your iphone safari browser, plug in: 192.168.1.x:4200 , where x = final digits of your ip address. Including the ":4200" was the difference for me.

Comment: @RafaëlMoser did you solve it ? I have the same issue and I'm cluless really.

Comment: Worked for me in Angular 14 and mac OS 13.2.1

Answer (score 27):

You can use the following command to access with your ip.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

If you are using npm and want to avoid running the command every time, we can add the following line to the **package.json** file in the **scripts** section.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"
    ...
}
```

Then you can run you app using the below command to be accessed from the other system in the same network.

```
npm start
```

Comment: It's now -disableHostCheck=true|false in my version, Angular 8.

Comment: this is working if you are not using ng serve

Answer (score 22):

I just edit `angular.json` file in my project as below and it works

```
...

    "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "project:build",
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 22):

No `package.json` is necessary to change.

For me it works using:

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5999 --disable-host-check
```

Host: http://localhost:5999/

Answer (score 17):

For the problem was Firewall. If you are on Windows, make sure node is allowed through
[image]

Comment: I was not able to access from the same network even after served with ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 . But firewall permission was the issue as you mentioned. Thanks for taking to time to share this one.

Comment: life saver. This should be added along the most voted answer

Answer (score 13):

In Angular version 11 (and maybe some earlier versions) `--public-host` option does the trick for me, for example:

```
$ ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host app.mypublicdomain.com
```

Answer (score 7):

If you facing same problem inside Docker, then you can use below `CMD` in Dockerfile.

```
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Or complete Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . .
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 7):

1. `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` will allow you to connect to the ng serve using your ip instead of localhost.

   Open your browser to <IP-ADDRESS>:4200
2. Using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` will allow you to connect to the ng serve using your domain instead of localhost.

   Open your browser to <DOMAIN-NAME>:4200

Answer (score 6):

Open cmd and navigate to project location i.e. where you run npm install or ng serve for the project.

and then run the command - `ng serve --host 10.202.32.45` where `10.202.32.45` is your IP address.

You will be able to access your page at `10.202.32.45:4200` where 4200 is your port number.

Note: **If you serve your app using this command then you won't be able to access `localhost:4200`**

Comment: Is it possible to access both way?

Comment: it works thanks..i guess i was looking at wrong ip address

Comment: know it sounds silly, but make sure your phone is using the same wifi network as you dev machine. I was using a guest network... +1 for the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution that might help someone :

Add this line as value for start `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`
in your `package.json`

ex:

```
{
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
"build": "ng build",
}
```

And then simply do `start` or `npm run start`

you will be able to access your project from other local IPs.

Answer (score 4):

you can also introspect all HTTP traffic running over your tunnels using **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)**
, then you can expose using `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 4200`

Answer (score 2):

Using ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 command has solved my issue. Use 192.168.x.x:5200 to get access to the app from another machine.

Also, check for firewall rules on client and server (disable firewall temporally or create a rule to allow traffic)

Answer (score 0):

- Use **`ng serve --host<Your IP> --port<Required if any>`**.
- ng serve --host=192.111.1.11 --port=4545.
- You can now see the below line at the end of compilation.

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on 192.111.1.11:4545, open your browser on `http://192.111.1.11:4545/` **.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

This worked for me perfectly (even using a public IP with an A host pointed to that IP).

Answer (score -1):

Create `proxy.conf.json` and paste this configuration

```
{  
"/api/*":
    {    
        "target": "http://localhost:7070/your api project name/",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
}
```

Replace:

```
let url = 'api/'+ your path;
```

Run from CLI:

```
ng serve  --host port.number —-proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Answer (score -1):

for me it works using "ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0" but there is a warning

---

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.

Answer (score -3):

For the people who are using node project manager, also this line adding to package.json will be enough. For angular CLI users, mast3rd3mon's answer is true.

You can add

```
"server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"
```

to package.json