# How to access AngularJS application on Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I've both NodeJS and AngularJS applications. I'm using `npm install` to download the app's dependencies for both the application. The NodeJS application runs on port `4000` and AngularJS application runs on port `4200`. I can access APIs from NodeJS application in the browser and cannot access the application's UI(AngularJS) in the browser. I have deployed these applications on Azure Virtual Machine.

I have opened the ports `4000` and `4200` in the network settings of Azure VM. I'm using `npm start` command to start both the applications. NodeJS working fine as like in the local machine but not the same case with AngularJS. There is no errors or warnings from AngularJS side. It shows that the app is listening on `http://localhost:4200/` and it is not accessible.

Comment: The AngularJS application needs listening on 0.0.0.0:4200 for outside connecting. Can you change it?

Comment: @NancyXiong How to change the ip in AngularJS? By default, It is showing like  `127.0.0.1:4200`

Comment: Try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` to allow that your AngularJS application is listening on `0.0.0.0` for outside connecting. You could refer to this [How to allow access outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```