# My node.js project run on http://localhost:8080/ but not run on my local ip 192.168.1.139:8080

Tags: node.js, http, localtunnel

My node.js project run on http://localhost:8080/ but not run on my local IP  192.168.1.139:8080

Actually, I am new in node.js. I have tried to search for information on google but could not get any solution.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: well.. did you write custom code or did you use the node `http-server` command on a shell? If it is a custom server you wrote.. please do share at least SOME of the code so we can understand what's going on

Comment: I got the project from git and make some changes according to my requirement. I go to the project directory and then write the command npm start. The project runs fine in http://localhost:8080/ but I want to show this running project to my senior on their pc.

Comment: well now i know it's custom made server(not a node problem) and the only thing i can think up of is that your personal computer has some security against that.. if you do know where the server file is.. pls send its content so we can see (another highly likely option is that the server chooses to `listen` specifically to localhost:8080)

Comment: I have installed webpack-dev-server for my project

Answer (score 1):

`192.168.1.139:8080` is not a localhost IP address. Try `127.0.0.1:8080` instead.

If you want to make this accessible on the internet you'll need to tunnel it, try https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should have one file called "web.bat" in your project class-path.
You need to configure your PC IP address in that file.
You can set the port number also in this file if you want to use some other port.

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080 --host 192.168.1.139
```

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost IP address is 127.0.0.1

You should try - 127.0.0.1:8080

all the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

`webpack-dev-server` has a host option to make the server available on the ipv4 address.
You could set the host to `0.0.0.0`

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost
`npx webpack serve --host 0.0.0.0`

The option is similar for other servers. There have also been other questions asked for it: [How to allow access outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

**For more context:**
https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

> In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local
> machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and
> a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable
> at both of those IPs