# Allow access from outside localhost - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ubuntu-20.04

I'm use `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` but when in I try to run my angular app using the url: "http://server_static_ip:port" from another host it doesn't work. It went on timeout and the browser said:

> "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: depends on what your network looks like. first thing is is your server accessible from the other host?  are there proxies/firewalls involved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost
See second answer, maybe you have the same issue.