# How to run an Angular2 app on mobile during development?

Tags: angular

I'm developing an Angular2 app. The app is served using `ng s --open`, and then the results can be seen at the browser at `http://localhost:4200`.

I also run a server at the same localhost, at port 3000. To connect to the server, Angular sends requests to `https://localhost:3000/some/api`.

The problem: when I run the Angular app on a mobile device (connected to the same WiFi), localhost:3000 is not reachable.

How can I run the app on a mobile device browser and still connect to the server at port 3000, while still running the app on `http://localhost:4200` on desktop (that connects to localhost:3000) *at the same time*?

Comment: Maybe you need this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a local network and then serve your angular project on local ip of your system with desired port.
For example:-
My system's local ip = 192.168.1.15
now **ng serve --host 192.168.1.15 --port 2600**

After successful compilation,
Open 192.168.1.15:2600 in your mobile device (ensure the mobile is connected to the WiFi in the same local network)