# Access Angular app running in windows from mac

Tags: angular, windows, macos

I am running a Angular App in my Windows machine. I am trying to connect this Windows machine from a MAC through WIFI and access the Angular application. I am unable to access it using Windows machine IP address.

Please help me on this. Will I be able to access as I mentioned above or not?

Note:
My windows is 11 Home edition

To be very clear on the way I connect MAC to my windows machine is through WIFI as below.

- I ran the application using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`.
- I created mobile hotspot in my windows machine.
- Connected to that hotspot from MAC.
- Then I am trying to access the application using the IP address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow access outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

Comment: Tl;dr - all network/machine settings aside, use `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` instead of `ng serve`. Then navigate to `http://{your_local_IPv4_address}:4200` instead of `http://localhost:4200` on whichever machine on your LAN you'd like to access the app from.

Comment: I am running the angular application using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` .
I have switched on mobile hotspot in my windows machine.

Then, I am connecting to the windows machine from mac through wifi by connecting to that hotspot and try to access using the IP address.

I am unable to access the angular application.