# Lightsail server - Cannot reach a port for angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have an angular app on a Lightsail server. It seems to run correctly

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF9uj.png)

I created the rule in the network tab

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0FuB.png)

But I cannot reach it from the outside ...

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onx2Z.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow access outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

You have to run ng serve with the sudo and host option .

Then access to your server in http if you didn't set the ssl.

sudo ng serve --host 0.0.0.0