# How to Access ASP.NET Web API Backend with Mobile Phone Android Browser using Angular Local Host

Tags: asp.net, angular, webapi

I am building my first web site (total newbie) using Angular and ASP.NET Web API. I can access my web app on localhost 4200 and using 192.168.100.2:4200 on my PC browser.

But when I try  to log on the same localhost with a Mobile Phone Android Browser, it returns a server error.

Following are the commands I tried:

```
ng serve --host 192.168.100.2
ng serve --host 192.168.100.2 --disable-host-check
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

This is my Login method on the Component

```
  login(){
    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      const record = this.loginForm.getRawValue();
      console.log(record);
      
      this.authService.login({
        username: record.userName,
        password: record.password,
      }).subscribe({
        next:(data: any) => {
                    this.authService.authToken = JSON.parse(data).token;
          console.log("Orig Token: ", data);
          console.log("Parsed Token: ", this.authService.authToken);
          console.log("Parsed Token (Subject): ", this.authService.authToken.split('.')[1]);
          console.log("JSON (after atob) ",this.authService.atob);
          console.log("Object (Payload): ",this.authService.payLoad);
          console.log("User id: ",this.authService.userID);
          console.log("Name: ",this.authService.userName);
          console.log("Modules: ",this.authService.accessibleModulesOfUser);

          this.router.navigateByUrl('');
          this.toastr.success("Welcome Back.")
        },
        error: (e) => {

                    if (e.status == 0) {
                        // this.msgs.push({ severity: 'warn', detail: 'Server is not available. Please try again later.' });
            // this.toastr.error("Server is not available. Please try again later")
            this.toastr.error("Server is not available. Please try again later")
                    }
                    else if (e.status == ApiCallStatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                        // this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', detail: err.error });
            // console.log(e);
            this.toastr.error(e.error)
                    }
                    else {
                        // this.msgs.push({ severity: 'warn', detail: err.error });
            // console.log(e);
            this.toastr.error(e.error)
                    }
        }
      })
    }
    else{
      this.toastr.warning("Enter username and password.")
    }
  }
```

I already try adding Inbound Rule to my Windows Defender Firewal but it doesnt work.

[image]

Also, I modify the CORS in startup of ASP.NET but still has no luck.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPIv5 v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://192.168.100.2:4200"));

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Usually you don't even need to specify a new firewall rule, if you have your network marked as your home network (instead of marking it as a public network). If this has been done, maybe you can check how you run your serve command. You can try serving it as `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` (as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

Comment: I already tried this command but still doesnt work.

Comment: [`192.168.x.x` addresses are not routed on the Internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/896456/what-makes-a-private-ip-address-not-routable), so you don't need to obfuscate or censor them.

Comment: _"But when I try to log on the same localhost with a Mobile Browser, It returns a server error."_ - **what is the error message, exactly?** If you really are getting a "server error" then your networking is working fine, you just need to fix a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` <-- This is probably it: your phone likely won't let you connect to a `https://` webserver that's using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I already editted my post , I pasted my login component so you can see. It returns error staus of zero so the Error is "Server is not available. Please try again later".

Comment: @Eugene What do you see in your browser's DevTools' Network window? There are _many_ reasons you can get `status === 0` in Angular's HTTP responses.

Comment: Sorry bro but I cant find devtools on mobile phones browser like in pc browser. I also hope there is devtools on phone to debug easily.