# Angular app refuse to show up on local browser after up and running on EC2 instance

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, ec2-ami

I was having issue with bringing up my angular app with node backend onto my local computer's browser after successfully having it up and running on EC2 instance. I have configured mmy security to allow traffic from port 4200 for angular and run ng serve with --host on the private IP as well as 0.0.0.0, but the issue persist, wondering what might caused the issue?

Here is my security config:

[image]

Also, here is the EC2 terminal output in which the angular app is hosted up successfully:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on what can actually gone wrong? Thanks

Edit:  I viewed the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost) before and attempts to use ng serve with --host 0.0.0.0, but it still does not work. But strangely, when I try port :80 it does connect to the ngnix web server I have on the EC2 instance on port 80, so that connect, but for the angular app on port 4200, it does not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow access outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost)

Comment: @AnonCoward Yeah I viewed that article before and attempts to use ng serve with --host 0.0.0.0, but it still does not work. But strangely, when I try port <public-ip>:80 it does connect to the ngnix web server I have on the EC2 instance on port 80, so that connect, but for the angular app on port 4200, it does not.

Comment: Have you tried to run with the ```--disable-host-check true``` option? And use ```0.0.0.0``` as the host, you will anyway not be able to connect if you bind it to the private IP of the EC2 instance.