# Call Api from public address

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, web, portforwarding

Scenario: On a web-server , IIS,  I have an Angular App with address 192.168.0.117:4444 that call an API (ASP.NET Core 7) on 192.168.0.117:5555. All works fine. Now I have a port forwarding that link the public address (here the fake 123.123.123.123:4444) of the web server to 192.168.0.117:4444, so I can open the Angular App and this works. But when I call API by the app, and capturing the error in console I receive an 'Unknown Error'.
The API CORS is configured in this way:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicyName,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://192.168.0.117:4444", "http://123.123.123.123:4444/")
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
// and then in the appropriate order:
app.UseCors(corsPolicyName);
```

Since everything works correctly in the private network, what should I do to make it work also from the public IP?
Thank you very much.

Before this I tested the API in private network, enabled CORS and also tested with PostMan.

Comment: An IP in the 192.x.x.x range will refer to the user's own network when they run the angular app on their computer, so Angular won't be able to reach your server unless you add a public ip / proxy to your back-end and have Angular call that IP.

Comment: does this issue related with allow access outside localhost answer your question?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost

Comment: No Ruikai, the scenario is different.